# Como implementar dado genérico neste caso?

Tags: java, android, genéricos

Estou usando o ORMlite em meu aplicativo e quero implementar um tipo genérico no seguinte:

```
public interface AdminDao extends Dao<T, Integer> {
   ...
}
```

onde "T" seria o genérico.

Erro:

> Cannot resolve symbol T

[image: erro na IDE]

Comment: Saindo um pouco da questão amigo, que IDE estas utilizando?

Comment: @Wakim a interface Dao é uma lib. Eu consegui corrigir este problema porém agora estou com outro quando gero os Overrides... http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml

Aqui tem todos arquivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você na declaração da interface tem também que indicar T

```
public interface AdminDao<T> extends Dao<T, Integer> {
   ...
}
```